# dynamic filter with dynamic content Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I would like to apply filter on products by catergory but i don't know how to do.

Here my HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="product in products | filter:search">
```

And here my filter :

```
 <li role="presentation" ng-repeat="category in categories">
 <a ng-click="FILTER WITH CAT NAME">{{category.name}}</a>
```

Here my controller where i receive data :

```
$http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/allProducts').
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log('------------ ProductsCtrl', data);
    console.log(data);

    $scope.products = data.products;
    $scope.categories = data.category;

    $scope.productsLength = data.products.length;
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    //
});
```

Someone can explain me how to do please i tried many things / times but nothing work for me...

thanks

Comment: Why was this upvoted?  It is virtually impossible to see what you are doing.  What is "FILTER WITH CAT NAME"?  are you listing your categories and then expecting the category to appear when the user clicks the expression which isn't shown?

Comment: @xeon48 is correct, you better show us your FILTER WITH CAT NAME method :)

Comment: Thanks for reply, I'm listing category (filter) and my products and i want to apply filter on produtcs. When i click on cat my list of product going to be filter and show only products with the selected cat. I don't have more code to show because i really don't know where i begin to do this. I read lot exemple but the data are directly in the code, but i charge data with an api so i just put my products and cat in the scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your list of products contain product objects with a category property. Add a select for your categories:

```
<select ng-model="selectedCategory" >
   <option ng-repeat="category in categories" value="{{category}}">{{category}}</option>
</select>
```

Then you can filter the products like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products | filter:category=selectedCategory">
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: it works perfectly thanks very much, how can i have an "all" categori otherwise have option with no filter display all products ?

Comment: Find just add this : <option value="{{category.$}}" selected>All category</option>